# Microsoft Application Insights - Exporting

Tags: export, azure-application-insights

I've been looking into Microsoft Application Insights and I find it useful and easy to work with.

However, when I get to the exporting bit I come up with questions. The main one is - is it possible to extract data from Microsoft App Insights into another database, different from the Azure one?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to export Azure Application Insights Data.

- You can export telemetry data from [Application Insights using Continuous Export](https://dailydotnettips.com/export-telemetry-data-from-application-insights-using-continuous-export/). Continuous export allows export telemetry data periodically and pushes it to Azure storages.
- While Continuous Export is one of the common ways to export data, you can leverage another feature from [Application Insights - Export to Excel](https://dailydotnettips.com/exporting-application-insights-data-to-excel-its-just-a-single-click/). You can export data for specific events or metrics to excel.
- You can also bring your [Application Insight data to Power BI](https://dailydotnettips.com/get-your-application-insights-data-in-power-bi-faster-than-ever/).
- Finally, you can access [Application Insight data using Rest API](https://dailydotnettips.com/query-application-insights-telemetry-data-using-rest-api/). So, have your own logic to get the data feed from Application Insights

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an option to download the old data from Application Insight, you have to use [REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) because **Continuous Export** option will not support. Also if you are trying to export large amount of data, you may reach the [API limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits). To overcome this, I wrote a simple python script to export data without reaching the limits.

https://gist.github.com/satheeshpayoda/92065d9fbaf5b0158728a8537d79af0e